# What is the correct way to check for null as a function return in Java

Tags: java, null

Please refer to Comment 1, 2 in the code below-

In swift, a function can have an optional return type that can be unwrapped when calling the function using Guard. I am curious to know the right way to handle returning optional for such cases in Java.

```
static Integer doCalc(Integer num1, Integer num2, char operation) {

        switch(operation) {

        case 'a':
            return num1 + num2;

        case 's':
            return num1 - num2;

        case 'm':
            return num1 * num2; 
        case 'd':

            return num2 != 0 ? num1 / num2 : -1; // **COMMENT 1**

        default: 
            System.out.println("not a valid operation. use 'a' 's' 'm' 'd'");
            return -1; // **COMMENT 2**

        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022319/null-check-error-message-as-is-null-or-was-null/3022334#3022334

Answer (score 1):

A primitive `int` (or any other primitive, for that matter), cannot be `null`. You could use the wrapper class (`java.lang.Integer`, in this case), and return `null` for erroneous input and an autoboxed value on valid input:

```
static Integer doCalc(int num1, int num2, char operation) {
    switch(operation) {
        case 'a':
            return num1 + num2;
        case 's':
            return num1 - num2;
        case 'm':
            return num1 * num2; 
        case 'd':
            return num2 != 0 ? num1 / num2 : null;
        default: 
            System.out.println("not a valid operation. use 'a' 's' 'm' 'd'");
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when the operation is invalid and an `ArithmeticException` when trying to divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would throw an Exception. 
Eg.

```
static int doCalc(int num1, int num2, char operation) {

    switch(operation) {

    case 'a':
        return num1 + num2;

    case 's':
        return num1 - num2;

    case 'm':
        return num1 * num2; 
    case 'd':
        if (num2 == 0) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot divide by zero");
        }
        return num1 / num2;

    default: 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid operation. use 'a' 's' 'm' 'd'");
    }
}
```